# method invocation pattern vs function invocation pattern

Tags: javascript

Reading *JavaScript Good Parts*, I come across two patterns to call a function:

// Method Invocation

```
var myObject = {
    value: 0;
    increment: function (inc) {
        this.value += typeof inc === 'number' ? inc : 1;
    }
};

myObject.increment(  );
document.writeln(myObject.value);    // 1

myObject.increment(2);
document.writeln(myObject.value);    // 3
```

// Function Invocation

```
myObject.double = function (  ) {
    var that = this;    // Workaround.

    var helper = function (  ) {
        that.value = add(that.value, that.value)
    };

    helper(  );    // Invoke helper as a function.
};

// Invoke double as a method.

myObject.double(  );
document.writeln(myObject.getValue(  ));    // 6
```

The method invocation pattern makes sense. However, in the function invocation pattern, he says "When a function is not the property of an object, then it is invoked as a function". Well wait a second, isn't the double function a property of myObject? I assume here that myObject is an object literal although it doesn't show its initialization in text. So if it is an object literal, then there is no difference between the two patterns. All we are doing is augmenting a value to the literal. Further, does anyone know where this getValue() is coming from?

I know that these two are indeed distinct in some way, since this in function invocation refers to global context in function invocation, whereas it refers to object itself in method invocation pattern.

Comment: *""When a function is not the property of an object..."* The `helper` function is not a property of the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is in how the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) works inside a function. The <s>odd</s> interesting thing is that in JavaScript it doesn't depend on how the function is defined, but how it is called:

If the function is called as `helper()`, you cannot use `this` (with a meaningful value) in the `helper` code.

If the function is called as `myObject.double()`, we call that a "method invocation", and `this` in the `double` code is the `myObject` as expected.

Comment: where is getValue() coming from? I don't see its definition anywhere.

Comment: That's probably some helper method defined earlier and just returns `myObject.value`.

Comment: ok so then myObject really is an object literal. It's just that inner function helper() is what is the function invocation.

Comment: Hey I mark this correct, but I would really appreciate some input if this is a bad design pattern or not.

Comment: The expression that is assigned to `myObject` in your first snippet is an object literal, yes; but that's irrelevant for the method invocation topic. There `myObject` just needs to be any object with a `double` property whose value is a function.

Comment: Bad design pattern? It's not a pattern, it's just how the language works. You will use some functions as pure functions, and some functions as methods, and you will need to watch out when you mix it (a function that is *supposed* to be invoked as a method, but is not, will fail more or less and wreak havoc on your program). However, the local `helper` function in the `double` method in your second snippet is superfluous, making this a bad example.

Comment: This is confirmed a mistake in the book.  It should be myObject.value.  Please see:

http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=9780596517748

FYI I believe (I am just working through this book also) that value is a property on Object which all objects inherit (hopefully someone could confirm that).

Comment: @mickeysox - value is a property defined on the `myObject` object (page 77 in my book) it is not inherited from the `Object.prototype`

Answer (score 0):

This example in the book really confused me for some reason. I reworked his example to better match his explanation (IMHO)

```
var myObject = {
    value: 1,
    double: function() {
        that = this;
        var inner = function() { that.value = that.value + that.value; };
        inner();     // Functional invocation
    }
};
myObject.double();  // Method invocation
console.log(myObject.value);
```

**Method Pattern**

The *double* method is invoked using the method pattern, therefore `this` is bound to `myObject`

**Functional Pattern**

The *inner* method is invoked using the functional pattern, therefore `this` is bound to the global object instead of `myObject`

Notice the lack of affect on the `value` property if you modify the *double* method as follows:

```
double: function() {
    var inner = function() { this.value = this.value + this.value; };
    inner();
 }
```